# MATLAB: finding index of an element in a multidimensional cell array with mixed data types

Tags: matlab, find, cell-array

Like the title says. How do I find the index of a specific element in a matlab cell array? The content of the cell array contains both strings and numbers.

Toy example:

```
database = cell(4,2)
database(1,1:2) = {'Song', 'Rating'}
database(2:4,1) = {'Song1'; 'Song2'; 'Song3'}
database(2:4,2) = {1; 2; 5}

functionIWant(database, 'Song2') % Should return [3,1] or something similar
```

I know I can convert it to a matrix, iterate over it and thereby find the right index. I'm wondering however if there is any faster method working directly on cell arrays.

Comment: +1 for including toy example. All questions should do that

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
[r,c] = find(strcmp(database,'Song2'))
```

Output -

```
r =
     3
c =
     1
```

Comment: Oh, `strcmp` works directly on cell arrays? Convenient.

Comment: @Jigg Exactly! Easier this way I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```
str='Song2';
Match=cellfun(@(x) strcmp(str, x), database, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

And get the index of the match:

```
[row, col]=find(cell2mat(Match))
```

If you want the matching element of column 2, just do:

```
database(row, 2)
```